# Mysqli_query error on javascript refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I have a queue system which retrieves data from a mysql table and says the position the person is in the mysql table.  The code works correctly when you manually refresh it, but I wanted to automatically refresh it.  I tried to put a button on it like so.  Although I know how to set it to automatically refresh, I understand buttons better and would like to figure this out with a button first.  This is the function I use when I click the button:

`function refresh() {
document.location.reload(true);
}`

When I click the button, it says
         Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given.
I do not understand this seeing as to how when it is manually refreshed it works properly.
The mysqli_query it is talking about is this`$query1 = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO names (id, text, amount) VALUES (NULL,     $name, $value)");`

Any help here would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At least your column "test" seems to be a string field, so enclose its value properly:

```
$query1 = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO names (id, text, amount) VALUES (NULL, '$name', $value)");
```